# Angularjs $scope manipulation, easy one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm tired, so probably I'm foreseeing something so I feel like asking some of you fresh heads :)

in my controller I get an object with more than one property from server side and I save it to $scope like

```
$scope.cool = EvilObject.get({id: $routeParams.id});
```

So now I want to manipulate one of the properties of this object before I use it in HTML (example *EvilObject.evilList*) and to send back just this changed property.

How can I create new $scope from this existing one, just to get that property. (in HTML I would of course do cool.evilList)
but like I said I want to do it here something like

```
$scope.cool = EvilObject.get({id: $routeParams.id});
$scope.evilThings = cool.evilList;
$scope.evilThingsArray = evilThings.split("#");
```

How it is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using angular resource to get your 'EvilObject', so you need to use the success callback  function to change your data, e.g. like this:

```
$scope.cool = EvilObject.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(data) {
  $scope.evilThings = data.evilList;
  $scope.evilThingsArray = $scope.evilThings.split("#");
});
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) in the Example section.

Comment: do resource actions really not return a usable promise ??

Comment: If you want to use the promise on a $resource you need to use `.$promise` at the end! But it would be the same effect, so using the success callback is the better way! ;)